# How can i publish the same collection under different names in a Meteor app?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my application I have a collection that is a list of videos, which bring only the videos of the authenticated user and would like to publish the same collection to bring the latest 5 videos but from all users. I'm doing the following but without success:

```
//CLIENT
PlayLists = new Meteor.Collection('playlists');
LatestLists = new Meteor.Collection("latestlists");

Meteor.autosubscribe(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('playlists', Session.get('listkey'));
    Meteor.subscribe('latestlists');    
});

Template.latestlist.latest = function(argument) {
    return LatestLists.find({});
};
Template.list.playlist = function(argument) {
    return PlayLists.find({});
};

//SERVER
PlayLists = new Meteor.Collection('playlists');
LatestLists = new Meteor.Collection("latestlists");

Meteor.publish('playlists', function (playlist) {
  return PlayLists.find({}, {user:this.userId()}); 
});
Meteor.publish('latestlists', function(){
  return PlayLists.find({}, {sort:{when:-1}, limit:5}); 
});
```

When i run the app, my latestlist collection allways is empty. what is the best way to achive this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Meteor `livedata` package does some magic with collections & subscriptions when you return a Cursor in `Meteor.publish(..)`.

Tom Coleman gave a good example of how you can bend Meteor to do what you are looking for here: [In Meteor how can I publish one server side mongo collection under different names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751790/in-meteor-how-can-i-publish-one-server-side-mongo-collection-under-different-nam?rq=1#comment15629962_11764189)

Essentially you should do as he suggested, either:-

- Call that internal `_publishCursor` function passing  in your `PlayLists.find({})` cursor and `latestlists` as your subscription name.

-Or-

- Copy the `_publishCursor` function and put it into a package for reusability.

Both approaches would work and I'd favour the latter as I am always wary about calling internal functions as they are liable to change underneath you.